# Run WP inside a other Site without using frames

Tags: plugins, themes

We have to put a Wordpress-Site inside an other website without doing this using frame/iframe, so the header, navigation e.g. comes from the parent site.

A blank parent site fragment with markers for header, content exists. This should be loaded by the theme or a plugin and markers replaced by the wordpress outputs.

So what's the best way to do that? Are there any plugins for such a strange requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Is your other website in the same server?

You can include `wp-load.php` to your other website (located in the root of your wordpress installation) and get the content from there. Of course you'll have to include stuff like the javascript libraries and the css used in wordpress (mainly those used in front end).

For different servers, you can get the data via RSS but only text content and images pointed inside RSS. You could also make pages that return you a jsonp object and use javascript on the other website to render your content.

Comment: Unfortunately the parent site is on an other server. And we have also no access to this machine. So the logic has to be in side wordpress.

Comment: Since you'll be serving your content to the other website, you have to get a hold with a developer there and he has to guide you with how you'll continue. I am guessing a jsonp service is the best choice you have to deliver your content there.